# Calling Kotlin from Java (cannot find symbol)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, cocos2d-x

I am trying to call a function in Kotlin from Java.
Documentation says that it is easy. I have follow this post without luck so far.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions

When typing in Java, the IDE recognizes the class but when I compile it says
*error: cannot find symbol*

Any help is more than welcome.

app.kt

```
package org.cocos2dx.cpp

fun getTime() { /*...*/ }
```

AppActivity.java

```
    public void test1() {
        org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppKt.getTime();
    }
```

Project structure

```
/proj.android
   /app
       /src
          /org.cocos2dx.cpp
              app.kt
              AppActivity
```

project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() 
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module level build.gradle

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "demo.1"
        minSdkVersion PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode 43
        versionName "0.43"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets 'MyGame'
                arguments "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters = []
            abiFilters.addAll(PROP_APP_ABI.split(':').collect{it as String})
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        java.srcDir "src"
        res.srcDir "res"
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
        assets.srcDir "../../Resources"
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "../../CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
            if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true
        }
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def project_root_folder = "${projectDir}/../.."
    def dest_assets_folder = "${projectDir}/assets"

    delete dest_assets_folder
    def targetName = variant.name.capitalize()
    def copyTaskName = "copy${targetName}ResourcesToAssets"
    
    tasks.register(copyTaskName) {
        copy {
            from "${buildDir}/../../../Resources"
            into "${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${variant.dirName}"
            exclude "**/*.gz"
        }
    }
    tasks.getByName("pre${targetName}Build").dependsOn copyTaskName
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':libcocos2dx')
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

Error

```
error: cannot find symbol
        org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppKt.getTime();
                        ^
  symbol:   class AppKt
  location: package org.cocos2dx.cpp
```

Comment: Do you have `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` in gradle project level, and `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"` dependency ?

Comment: No I don't. I added and it is complaining that kotlin_version variable is unknown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks fine; but you need to have the **project level build.gradle** class path:

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}
```

And the Kotlin standard library dependencies in **build.gradle module level**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" 
}
```

Finally, add the following to the **module-level build.gradle** at top-level of the file:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
```

Comment: Hi @Zain, thank you for your suggestions.  I added them but still AppKt is not found.  I've edited my post and added my build.gradles

Comment: Hey @MarcelaNievas Can you also add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` .. it's at the top level of the Module level build.gradle along aside with other plugins

Comment: Yes !!!, that was the last piece I needed into this puzzle :D It is working thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this provlem  by moving the java file under a java sources directory and then keeping the kotlin kt file under the kotlin sources.

Your file structure might look more like this afterwards:

```
proj.android/
├─ app/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ kotlin/
│  │  │  ├─ org.cocos2dx.cpp/
│  │  │  │  ├─ app.kt
│  │  ├─ java/
│  │  │  ├─ org.cocos2dx.cpp/
│  │  │  │  ├─ AppActivity
```

In multiprojects(using JPMS) i additionally had to add

```
compileKotlin.destinationDir = compileJava.destinationDir
```

to my build.gradle.

Comment: I added to my module build.gradle but compileJava.destinationDir is not defined.

Comment: Looking at your project you arent using JPMS so you shouldn't have to add the compilejava/kotlin bit. Make sure you redo your project structure to match!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your project and module level build.gradle files match the following:

```
 plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    }

    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
        id 'kotlin-kapt'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **@JVMStatic** in kotlin function.

```
@JvmStatic
fun getTime() { /*...*/ }
```

from JAVA

```
public void test1() {
   AppKt.getTime();
}
```

This should work.